# Can't access images and fonts on production Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, assets

I access some static images (favicon, etc) through /assets/image.jpg.
It works as expected on localhost but when I push in production, I can't access fonts and images.
Css and js are compiled and working fine.

I've added this to my production.rb file but it still doesn't work :

```
 config.serve_static_files = true
 config.serve_static_assets = true 
 config.assets.compile = true
```

What do I have to write to access them and where ?

Comment: What server are you running in production?

Comment: It's an nginx running on ubuntu 14.04 on a digitalocean droplet. Precision : my images are uploaded to the folder fine, they are just not accessible through url

Comment: is it possibly a CDN or caching issue?

Comment: Mmh I don't know, why would it be ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured, it was dumb : 
In production we have to use rails link helpers to provide assets, for example, you can't access favicon with :

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/gif" href="/assets/images/favicon.gif"/>`

we have to use

`<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.gif' %>`

because a sha is generated and produces the following link for example

```
/assets/favicon-02168c53f101e2059920863c64a71d6abc53b4fbec334f2e0b002f7866e63b69.gif
```